# onSubmitEditing fires on every key press

Tags: react-native, vue-native

I'm trying to call a function whenever the user presses the "return" key on the keyboard.

Using the following code;

```
<text-input class="hashtags" placeholder="#Fashion" v-model="hashtagField" returnKeyType="done" :onSubmitEditing="addHashtag()" />
```

causes the function to fire on every key press.

I've tried looking for an answer to this weird problem, but I cannot seem to find a proper solution.

**Please note that I'm using Vue Native, which is a wrapper of React Native.**